# change cacheBlockSize in ag grid roleModelType infinite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag grid with react typescript, using roleModelType=infinite and everything works fine.
But i want to add dropdown of numbers to change pagination size that sends startIndex and endIndex params to backend. So i want to change value **paginationPageSize** and **cacheBlockSize**
but the problem is, I want to change "cacheBlockSize" in gridoptions when i change cacheBlockSize it give me error that

```
client.js?4d30:1 AG Grid: api.setCacheBlockSize can only be called when gridOptions.rowModelType is serverSide
```

```
 <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }} size="small">
              <Select labelId="demo-select-small" id="demo-select-small" value={cacheBlockSize.toString()} onChange={onCacheBlockSizeChange}>
     <MenuItem value={50}>50</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={100}>100</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={200}>200</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={5}>5</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={3}>3</MenuItem>
     <MenuItem value={2}>2</MenuItem>
    </Select>
 </FormControl>
  <AgGridReact
     ref={gridRef}
     gridOptions={gridOptions}
     paginationPageSize={cacheBlockSize}
     cacheBlockSize={cacheBlockSize}
     onGridReady={onGridReady}>
 </AgGridReact>
```

Comment: you can rerender the grid when the new pagesize is selected